# Ember : if a value is set in controller , perform an Ajax command(written in template),

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I have given a rough code to understand what I need to perform,

/app/route1/controller.js

```
export default Controller.extend({
    test: function(id) {
        $.ajax({
            .....
            .....
            .....
        }).then(() => {
           set('message','successfully added');
        });
    }
});
```

/app/route1/template.hbs

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui segment"
    <button class="ui button" {{action "test" model.id}}>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui modal">
    <div class="header"
      Message
    </div>
    <div class="content"
      {{message}}
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="ui ok button">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    if(message) {
      $('.ui.modal').modal('show');   
    }
  })
</script>
```

If I set a message in controller then, I have to show this message in the MODAL. The Ajax command that I've written is not correct., Please help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `set('message','successfully added');` probably should be `this.set('message','successfully added');` or `set(this, 'message','successfully added');`. Also you probably wanna place the `test` function under `actions`. Oh, and why the the `<script>` tag?

Comment: `<scirpt>` tag is to initialise the `modal`, actually we have to set a click event listener in the `script tag`

Comment: you *must not* use `<script>` tags with ember.

Comment: @Sreenath I explained exactly how to set up event listeners when I answered you a few days ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149734/ember-handlebars-how-can-i-make-an-ajax-or-jquery-call-for-an-handlebar-file

Answer (score 0):

First, you *must not* use `<script>` tags with ember. This won't work as expected and is in no way supported.

*If* you have to manually access DOM you should use the `didInsertElement` of a component.

Are you absolutly sure you want to build your modal yourself? There are [many addons providing a nice API for modals](https://www.emberobserver.com/categories/modals). If you can use one of them. If you cant you basically have to write your own `modal` component.

I will not instruct your in detail how to do this, because this seems not to be your primary question.

Now about your `test` function. first you seem to try to use it as an action:

```
{{action "test" model.id}}
```

however for this you must place the function under the `actions` hash.

Next this line is wrong:

```
set('message','successfully added');
```

you either must use `this.set('message','successfully added');` or `set(this, 'message','successfully added');`

Then you can display your message like this:

```
{{#if message}}
  {{#modal-dialog
    onClose=(action (mut isShowingBasic) false)
  }}
    {{message}}
  {{/modal-dialog}}
{{/if}}
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: {{#modal-dialog}} not working. I have installed the addon

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? And which add-on? You can choose of of many or even implement that component yourself.

Comment: https://www.emberobserver.com/addons/ember-modal-dialog - This is the add-on I have used

Comment: And as I use the latest version of ember, it seems that ember-modal-dialog is not compatible with the latest version of ember ( in the site )

Comment: what do you mean by *not working*? Do you get an error? How is it *not working*?

Comment: It works. [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/158a0788384f9a5c3d06a253ea8ccf4a?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) is a working twiddle.